# run mysqldump from C# App not working

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to run a mysqldump on a button klick of my c# app.

on the command prompt i use this command (and it is working):

```
         mysqldump -u root --password=pwd mydb > exportfile.sql
```

this command doesn't work in my c# app. 
i use this code:

```
            ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(@"mysqldump", "-u root --password=pwd mydb > exportfile.sql");                
            Process.Start(p);
```

but mysql quits with an error message:
"couldn't find table ">"

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

">" is a DOS command that redirects the output of a program into a file.

You can't use it in Process.Start - it is just considered to be a parameter for the program you're executing.

If you want to capture the output of a process, you'll need to redirect its stdout yourself. See [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx). You'll then need to read this output stream and write it to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's not supported to redirect the output within a hosted Process. If that's the case, then you can [redirect the standard output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and write the file by yourself.